# awk not capturing first line / separator

Tags: bash, awk

I don't understand the following behaviour:

This is a text file:

```
example.txt
12345   4321    hello hello this is a test  blobb
14324   2131    another test , incoming !   blubb
52341   1231    last test now shutting down bla
...
```

It consists of x rows of text, 4 tab-separated columns each. I only need the first three, so I used awk (for the first time):

```
awk '{FS="\t"; OFS="\t"; print $1,$2,$3}' < example.txt > excerpt.txt
```

The result is this:

```
excerpt.txt
12345   4321    hello
14324   2131    another test , incoming !
52341   1231    last test now shutting down
...
```

The first entry does not contain the full third column, and printing `$1,$2,$3,$4` gives `12345 4321    hello hello` for the first row. So, apparently it separates at whitespace (both after the first and the second `hello`), and not at tab. I checked if a tab snuck in there, but that was not the case:

[image: ctrl+f, \t]

I find this very confusing, since it works correctly for all other rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the field separators on every line. Then, `awk` reads the record (line) but in the way it was when the cursor reached it, so the first time you are setting it is is *too late* to apply to the first record.

Since the default field separator is a space, on the first line it uses it. Then, from the second record, it takes into account what was previously set.

You need to set it either in the `BEGIN` block or before (the effect is the same):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2,$3}' example.txt > excerpt.txt

awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3}' example.txt > excerpt.txt
```

Alternatively, you can also "recompile" the record with something like `$1=$1`. This reinterprets the record based on the current field separators. So this should work as well:

```
awk '{FS=OFS="\t"; $0=$0; print $1,$2,$3}' example.txt > excerpt.txt
```

#### Test

Testing the last thing, on recompiling the field.

```
$ cat a
hello this      is me and
here we are     doing some awk
$ awk '{FS="\t"; print $2}' a
this
doing some awk
$ awk '{FS="\t"; $0=$0; print $2}' a
is me and
doing some awk
```

Comment: One minor note, the initial delimiter seems to be either whitespace or tab, as it separates at any of them.