# Confusion about awk command when dealing with if statement

Tags: awk

```
$ cat awk.txt 
12  32  45
5   2   3
33  11  33
$ cat awk.txt | awk '{FS='\t'} $1==5 {print $0}'
5   2   3
$ cat awk.txt | awk '{FS='\t'} $1==33 {print $0}'
```

Nothing is returned when judging the first field is 33 or not. It's confusing.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} $1==33' file`. Note you need to define FS in the `BEGIN` block and with double quotes.

Comment: @fedorqui I would see that if this was the first line but 33 is in the third line and the default `FS` will split on tabs (though the newly set `FS` of `t` won't work at all),

Comment: Is that actually the input file? Or is the line that matches the first line in the file and no other lines match?

Comment: @EtanReisner by saying `FS='\t'` any character is a different field. You can see it by saying `awk '{FS='\t'; print NR; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, $i} file`. So it works when `$1==5` because the first field is just one digit, but it does not when `$1==33` because it contains two. It would work if saying `$1==3`.

Comment: @fedorqui `awk '{FS='\t'...}'` is effectively `awk '{FS=t...}`... oh, not `"t"` but variable `t` which is empty and sets `FS` to the null string. I see.

Comment: Your awk command is being parsed by the shell as `[awk] [{FS=][t][} $1==33 {print $0}]`. The single quotes are pairing up in ways you weren't expecting. You wanted double quotes in the awk script, awk doesn't use single quotes for strings anyway.

Comment: $ cat awk.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} $1==33 {print $0}'  #It doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

By saying

```
awk '{FS='\t'} $1==5 {print}' file
```

You are defining the field separator incorrectly. To make it be a tab, you need to say `"\t"` (with double quotes). Further reading: [awk not capturing first line / separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30946244/1983854).

Also, you are setting it every line, so it does not affect the first one. You want to use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS='\t'} $1==5' file
```

Yes, but why did it work in one case but not in the other?

```
awk '{FS='\t'} $1==5' file  # it works
awk '{FS='\t'} $1==33' file # it does not work
```

You're using single quotes around `'\t'`, which means that you're actually concatenating 3 strings together: `'{FS='`, `\t` and `'} $1==5'` to produce your awk command. The shell interprets the `\t` as `t`, so your awk script is actually:

```
awk '{FS=t} $1==5'
```

The variable `t` is unset, so you're setting the field separator to the empty string `""`. This means that the line is split into as many fields as characters you have. You can see it doing `awk 'BEGIN{FS='\t'} {print NF}' file`, that will show how many fields each record has.

Then, `$1` is just `3` and `$2` contains the second `3`.

Comment: Surely the shell will interpret `\t` as `t`, so the field separator will be the character `t`? Why does that cause each character to be interpreted as a field?

Comment: @TomFenech The shell sticks the character `t` into the awk script and awk sees `FS=t` which isn't `FS="t"` but rather an empty variable. I had the same confusion.

Comment: @EtanReisner good explanation, I knew the *what* but was also still trying to understand the *why*

Comment: @TomFenech as always, thanks for your clarifications in all senses: clarity and grammar : D

Answer (score 0):

first of all !. Could you explain better what you really want to do before you ask ?.  look....!

```
more awk.txt
  12  32  45
  5   2   3
  33  11  33


  awk -F"[ \t]" '$1 == 5 { print $0}' awk.txt
  5   2   3

  awk -F"[ \t]" '$1 == 33 { print $0}' awk.txt
  33  11  33

  awk -F"[ \t]" '$1 == 12 { print $0}' awk.txt
  12  32  45
```

http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_23.html

Fcs